# Issue with dynamic html generating form ejs template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

Trying to make search function on ejs page. Ejs page works and shows all of my styles, texts etc, but when im trying to search something, there is no result on page. On my mind, when im trying to search, below search bar appears block - generated from ejs template.
Also i tried to search with static pages - html, in this case search works perfect.
Tried watch console log on browser, in logs there is search request on network. In request, i see correct result of search, but nothing else.

Here is part of client code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const searchForm = document.querySelector('#search-form');
  const searchResults = document.querySelector('#search-results');



  searchForm.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const searchText = searchForm.elements.text.value;

    const response = await fetch('/search', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ text: searchText })
    });

    const json = await response.json();

    if (json.length === 0) {
      searchResults.innerHTML = 'no result';
      return;
    }

    const html = await ejs.renderFile('./views/search-results.ejs', { results: json });
    searchResults.innerHTML = html;
  });
});
```

Comment: Please check the `json` and `html`. What did you get?